# Can't seem to add code directly in Firefox's event inspector

Tags: javascript, web, firefox, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

After clicking the `event` button , Firefox Dev Tools will show the handler associated with it.

How can I edit that function to add code (eg `alert(1)`) to it?

[image]

Comment: Basically, you can't. You can open it in the debugger (button the the right of the line telling you where the code is from), but even there you can't change the code.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to switch to the Debugger panel by clicking the the button to the right of the event.

Though there is currently (as of Firefox 86) to edit the code in the Debugger. There's [a very old feature request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=771339) (created by a Mozilla staff member) for it, though, which you may want to follow.

What you can do, though, is to [set a breakpoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint) at the position which you want to investigate to stop the script execution at that code statement.

Or if you just want to output some variable value when that code is executed, you can also [set a logpoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/Set_a_logpoint) instead.